# simple 2d collision problem

Tags: c++, collision-detection, computational-geometry

I want to find when a collision between a static and a moving ball occurs, but the algorithm I came up with, sometimes doesn't detect a collision and the moving ball goes through the static one. The moving ball is affected by gravity and the static one is not.

Here's my collision detection code:

```
GLfloat whenSpheresCollide(const sphere2d &firstSphere, const sphere2d &secondSphere)
{
    Vector2f relativePosition = subtractVectors(firstSphere.vPosition, secondSphere.vPosition);
    Vector2f relativeVelocity = subtractVectors(firstSphere.vVelocity, secondSphere.vVelocity);

    GLfloat radiusSum = firstSphere.radius + secondSphere.radius;

    //We'll find the time when objects collide if a collision takes place

    //r(t) = P[0] + t * V[0]
    //
    //d^2(t) = P[0]^2 + 2 * t * P[0] * V[0] + t^2 * V[0]^2
    //
    //d^2(t) = V[0]^2 * t^2 + 2t( P[0] . V[0] ) + P[0]^2
    //
    //d(t) = R
    //
    //d(t)^2 = R^2
    //
    //V[0]^2 * t^2 + 2t( P[0] . V[0] ) + P[0]^2 - R^2 = 0
    //
    //delta = ( P[0] . V[0] )^2 - V[0]^2 * (P[0]^2 - R^2)
    //
    //  We are interested in the lowest t:
    //
    //t = ( -( P[0] . V[0] ) - sqrt(delta) ) / V[0]^2
    //

    GLfloat equationDelta = squaref( dotProduct(relativePosition, relativeVelocity) ) - squarev( relativeVelocity ) * ( squarev( relativePosition ) - squaref(radiusSum)  );

    if (equationDelta >= 0.0f)
    {
        GLfloat collisionTime = ( - dotProduct(relativePosition, relativeVelocity) - sqrtf(equationDelta) ) / squarev(relativeVelocity);

        if (collisionTime >= 0.0f && collisionTime <= 1.0f / GAME_FPS)
        {
            return collisionTime;
        }
    }

    return -1.0f;
}
```

And here is the updating function that calls collision detection:

```
void GamePhysicsManager::updateBallPhysics()
{
    //
    //Update velocity
    vVelocity->y -= constG / GAME_FPS;  //v = a * t = g * 1 sec / (updates per second)

    shouldApplyForcesToBall = TRUE;

    vPosition->x += vVelocity->x / GAME_FPS;
    vPosition->y += vVelocity->y / GAME_FPS;

    if ( distanceBetweenVectors( *pBall->getPositionVector(), *pBasket->getPositionVector() ) <= pBasket->getRadius() + vectorLength(*vVelocity) / GAME_FPS )
    {
        //Ball sphere
        sphere2d ballSphere;
        ballSphere.radius = pBall->getRadius();
        ballSphere.mass = 1.0f;
        ballSphere.vPosition = *( pBall->getPositionVector() );
        ballSphere.vVelocity = *( pBall->getVelocityVector() );


        sphere2d ringSphereRight;
        ringSphereRight.radius = 0.05f;
        ringSphereRight.mass = -1.0f;
        ringSphereRight.vPosition = *( pBasket->getPositionVector() );
        //ringSphereRight.vPosition.x += pBasket->getRadius();
        ringSphereRight.vPosition.x += (pBasket->getRadius() - ringSphereRight.radius);
        ringSphereRight.vVelocity = zeroVector();


        GLfloat collisionTime = whenSpheresCollide(ballSphere, ringSphereRight);

        if ( collisionTime >= 0.0f )
        {
            DebugLog("collision");
            respondToCollision(&ballSphere, &ringSphereRight, collisionTime, pBall->getRestitution() * 0.75f );
        }

        //
        //Implement selection of the results that are first to collide collision

        vVelocity->x = ballSphere.vVelocity.x;
        vVelocity->y = ballSphere.vVelocity.y;

        vPosition->x = ballSphere.vPosition.x;
        vPosition->y = ballSphere.vPosition.y;
    }
```

Why isn't the collision being detected in 100% of cases? It's being detected only in 70% of cases.
Thanks.

UPDATE: Problem seems to be solved when I change FPS from 30 to 10. How does FPS affect my collision detection?

Comment: Well in that case try setting the FPS very high and debugging the program line-by-line, watching carefully how the variable-values coincide with what you think they should be.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the respondToCollision function? Specifially, does it recurse to detect a further collision with a third party? How do you handle multiple collisions in a frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delta = ( P[0] . V[0] )^2 - V[0]^2 * (P[0]^2 - R^2)
```

Shouldn't that be delta = b<sup>2</sup> - **4** ac?

---

**[Edit]** Oh I see, you factored the 4 out.  In that case, are you sure you're considering both solutions for t?

```
t = ( -( P[0] . V[0] ) - sqrt(delta) ) / V[0]^2
```

and

```
t = ( -( P[0] . V[0] ) + sqrt(delta) ) / V[0]^2
```

Comment: I'm using an alternative formula that can be used when coefficient before x is even.

Comment: I'm considering only one solution - the lesser time. I'm not interested in the bigger time because it will occur when the distance between objects will be 0 for the second time (collision itself occurs for lesser time).

Comment: It may very well be due to rounding errors - the program is expecting the collision to happen next frame, but, due to slight rounding errors, by the next frame the collision should have already happened. Try replacing your `floats` with `doubles`, or have the collision happen a few frames early (replace `collisionTime <= 1.0f / GAME_FPS` with, say, `collisionTime <= 1.9f / GAME_FPS`)

Comment: If replacing float with double fixes a problem, then your algorithm is wrong!  I do agree with BlueRaja's second statement, look at how you're handling collisionTime and make sure that you're not taking steps that are too big.

Comment: The "will the collision happen this frame" approximation could also be giving incorrect results because it doesn't account for the velocity changing from one frame to the next:  So whereas if the velocity were constant it would work (minus the rounding errors), the way it is now frame 2 may predict the collision will happen on frame 3, while frame 3 will say the collision happened on frame 2!

Answer (score 1):

How large are the sphere's and how fast are they moving? Can a sphere "jump" over the second one during a frame (i.e., is it's velocity vector longer than it's width?).

Along those lines, what happens if you remove the upper limit here:

```
if (collisionTime >= 0.0f && collisionTime <= 1.0f / GAME_FPS)
{
    return collisionTime;
}
```

If the sphere was moving too fast, maybe your algorithm is detecting a collision that happened more than one frame ago .. (?)

Comment: The spheres are approximately the same size.
Generally, this upper limit defines if the collision will happen during the next frame. If yes, it reports a collision.